# Docker COPY --chown ownership sometimes applies to

Tags: docker, aws-codepipeline, chown, docker-copy

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11

# Create non-root user to run with
ARG USERNAME=bean
ARG USER_UID=999
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME
COPY --chown=$USERNAME:$USERNAME . .
```

When I run the image, the copied subdirectories are owned by user bean, as is the working directory, `.`. When I build in AWS CodePipeline with the same build command, the copied subdirectories are owned by bean, but the `.` directory is owned by root. I can't reproduce the issue when building locally, even if I change ownership of the host directory to root or build as root. How can I make sure `.` is always owned by bean?

Comment: Have you tried an explicit `RUN chown $USERNAME:USERNAME .`?

Comment: @larsks I wanted to avoid the additional chown, and I'm mostly just confused as to why this would happen on some hosts but not others